# Why does the vertical size of the scroll bar change?

Tags: browser

When I scroll down a web page the scroll bar appears and constantly changes size as I scroll
 What does this size relate to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some websites load new content as you scroll down the page, to prevent new page requests thus reducing bandwith. i.reddit.com is one off the top of my head, the Market app does this also.

Comment: Are you sure about this? The messaging view does this as well…

Comment: Yes, it definitely happens. Try going to i.reddit.com in stock browser and see what happens as you scroll down - you never run out of content.

Answer (score 2):

The scrollbar is related to the size of the content of the webpage you are looking at.  If it the scrollbar is changing size, then that means the content on the page is likewise changing size (via asynchronous calls that retrieve more data for that webpage as you are browsing it).